# How to format NumberCells in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I have a cell table that contains Number Columns, added via the GWT Designer plugin for eclipse. These equate to `Column<MyObject, Number>(new NumberCell())`

I can't figure out how via the API to designate formatting for the cells. The default behavior for integers is to use the a "thousands seperator", e.g. 123456 as 123,456. I want to display just the plain number.

I suppose I could just use a Text column, and frankly, I'm not sure what having a Number Column really buys me, since the column isn't editable (but may be some day), and I have to apply my own Comparator for sorting.

Should I just use a plain text column, or is there a way to specify number formatting on the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberCell` uses a `NumberFormat` to format the number, using the [decimal format](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html#getDecimalFormat%28%29) if none is provided.

You can provide another `NumberFormat` of your choice, and if it still doesn't fit your needs (you want a plain `toString()`) you can simply create your own cell inheriting `AbstractCell`.

Comment: I just discovered that in the constructor.. I was looking for mutator methods, not a constructor argument. I ended up using NumberFormat.getFormat("") to do what I needed.